# A statistical relation for pressure

Tags: statistical-mechanics, pressure

I know that the distribution function for fermions/bosons in phase space is $$f_{i}=\frac{g_{i}}{h^{3}}\frac{1}{e^{(E_{i}-\mu_{i})/k_{B}}\pm1},$$ with plus sign for fermions and minus sign for bosons, and $g_{i}$ being the spin degrees of freedom for particle type $i$.

I also know that in order to find the energy density of particle type $i$ per unit volume of position space, I need to integrate over the momentum  space, that is $E_{i}=\int E_{i}f_{i}d^{3}p$.

Now if I am to find the pressure due to particle type $i$, what integral should I deal with? I have come to find a relation, $p_{i}=\int(\frac{p^{2}}{3E_{i}})f_{i}d^{3}p$, but I don't understand where the term in parentheses come from. What does $\frac{p^{2}}{3E_{i}}$ have to do with pressure?

Comment: The answer for your question is presented here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/430802/122611

Answer (score 1):

The formula looks strange. Are you sure you typed it right? As far as I can see the dimension of right hand side is that of density, not of pressure.

Pressure is related to grand potential (or Landau potential): $p = - \Omega/V$. For quantum ideal gases expression of $\Omega$ is well known. If $E_i$ depends on $p$ in a simple manner, than relation between $\Omega$ and $E$ can occurs.

For $E_i = p^2/2m$ we have $\Omega = -2E/3$, and for $E_i = cp$ relation is $\Omega = -E/3$.

Comment: Yes, I have typed it right.

Comment: Can you please give reference on the source of this formula?

Comment: A cosmology pamphlet. It doesn't look like to be wrong, since I used this formula to find the well-known relation between pressure and temperature for non-relativistic particles, $p=nT$, and it really worked. On the other hand, the dimension of pressure is $J/m^{3}$, thus the dimension of the term in parentheses must be $J$, but it is $[\frac{E_{i}}{c^2}]$.