# Derivation of relativistic pressure

Tags: statistical-mechanics, cosmology, pressure, quantum-statistics

As you can find in many cosmology textbooks, the relativistic pressure in quantum statistical mechanics can be witten as below:

$$p=g \int \frac{d^3P}{(2 \pi \hbar)^3} \frac{c^2 |\mathbf{P}|^2}{3E(\mathbf{P})}f(\mathbf{P})\tag{D.1.4}$$

where $f(\mathbf{P})$ is the fermi/bose distribution function:
$$f(\mathbf{P})=\frac{1}{\exp[\frac{E(\mathbf{P})-\mu}{k_B T}]\pm 1}\tag{D.1.1}$$
and the relativistic energy $E(\mathbf{P})$ is as usual:
$$E(\mathbf{P})=\sqrt{c^2|\mathbf{P}|^2+m^2 c^4}$$

I want to know how to derive the first equation, particularly the portion of $\frac{c^2 |\mathbf{P}|^2}{3E(\mathbf{P})}$.

Any comment and help would be appreciated.

References:

1. http://tmcosmos.org/cosmology/cosmology-web/node31.html (Japanese).

Comment: Start by looking into a statistical mechanics book, using the properties of bosons you can construct thermodinamic potential from which you can derive this formulas. The easiest way is to start with the grand canonical potential, calculate the partition function and grand potential and then derive the potential with respect to the volume at temperature and chemical potential fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider a particle bouncing back and forth between two walls parallel to yz-plane separated by length $L_x$. The momentum of the particle in the normalized direction of the walls is $p_x$, so a momentum change of $2p_x$ occurs on every collision. The velocity of the particle in the direction is $v_x = c^2 p_x/E$ because
$$p_x = \gamma m v_x, \quad E = \gamma m c^2.$$
Then the time between collisions is $2L_x/v_x$. The average force on the wall is
$$F_{\text{av}} = \frac{\Delta p_x}{\Delta t} = \frac{2 p_x}{2L_x E/p_x c^2} = \frac{1}{L_x} \frac{c^2p_x^2}{E}.$$
Dividing both sides by the area of the walls, $L_y L_z$, we have the pressure
$$P = \frac{1}{V} \frac{c^2p_x^2}{E}.$$
Finally, we sum over all the particles by integrating over the phase space density, giving 
$$P_{\text{tot}} = \int d\mathbf{p} \, \frac{f(\mathbf{p})}{(2\pi \hbar)^3} \, \frac{c^2 p_x^2}{E}=\int d\mathbf{p} \, \frac{f(\mathbf{p})}{(2\pi \hbar)^3} \, \frac{c^2 p^2}{3E}.$$
Here, we use the relation which holds for average: $\langle p^2 \rangle = \langle p_x^2 \rangle + \langle p_y^2 \rangle + \langle p_z^2 \rangle = 3 \langle p_x^2 \rangle$. Since the integration sums over all the particles, we can use the relation which only holds for average.

Comment: What about the expansion of the Universe. That seems to be missing from this derivation.